# Выделяется ли "ну" запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, частица, междометие

В данном случае "ну" выделяется запятыми? 
*Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии ну вы поняли*

Answer (score 1):

Есть масса вариантов пунктуационного оформления. Вариант с выделением "ну" обычными запятыми - корректный, но не самый выразительный.

Я бы написала так.

***Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии - ну, вы поняли.***

Запятая после "ну" тут интонационная больше, чем смысловая. Можно безболезненно убрать, если автор такой интонации не предполагает.

***Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии - ну вы поняли.***

В перовом случае "ну" следует трактовать как междометие, во втором - как частицу. И то, и другое корректно.

Answer (score 1):

**Стандартное оформление:** Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии, **ну вы поняли.** В авторском варианте можно обособить **тире**, но **запятую после НУ лучше не ставить** (пауза там будет лишней, это единая присоединительная конструкция).

**Пример:** Но теперь, чтобы получить их бесплатно, приходится прилагать определенные материальные усилия, **ну вы меня понимаете**, ― сообщил «Известиям» главный специалист объединения «Автоглобус» Денис Ромашков.

**НУ ― многозначная чтица,** используется в разных ситуациях, в частности употр. для подтверждения согласия ( надеюсь, что вы меня поняли).

Answer (score 1):

> Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии ну вы поняли

Согласен с **IrinaGL** —  возможна масса вариантов пунктуационного оформления этого предложения.

Отметил бы допустимость  ещё одного варианта (не предложенного в других ответах), отражающего возможную незаконченность приведённого   списка (фотографий?),  —  **с  многоточием**:

***Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии…  ну, вы поняли***  (запятая после "ну" здесь факультативна).

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае "ну" выделяется запятыми? Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии ну вы поняли. 
Я думаю, что "ну" не надо выделять запятыми, также не надо его употреблять вообще, так как "ну" придаёт просторечный оттенок речи и, возможно, является словом-паразитом. Может быть, "ну" можно здесь заменить вводным оборотом "я думаю"? А вот после "биологии" надо бы поставить запятую.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с user183861 насчёт запятой **перед "ну"** и насчёт того, что **не нужна запятая** после, потому что "ну" здесь частица.

Не согласен только в том, что *ну* здесь "является словом-паразитом" или что этого выражения стоит избегать. Для официальной и письменной речи оно действительно не годится, а для непринуждённой приятельской беседу — почему бы нет?! Можно иногда вставить "надеюсь": *ну, надеюсь, вы поняли*. А можно и так оставить.

Возможно, это и современное выражение, которого раньше не было в языке, но в любом случае я не нахожу ничего плохого в нём.

Answer (score 0):

"Это я - на геометрии, физике, химии и биологии. Ну, вы поняли.

Ну... вы поняли?

Comment: Да не очень пока.

Comment: Пояснительная конструкция+просторечное устойчивое выражение. Как человек много общающийся с молодёжью на игровых сайтах, могу засвидетельствовать, что выражение, часто граничащее с т.н. "олбанским" и иногда выглядящее даже так -  "Нувыпонели", применяется очень часто для подведения итога написанного.

Answer (score 0):

"Ну" в данном случае - междометие, а не усилительная частица, поэтому запятая ставится после "ну". А перед междометием ставим тире, разделяющее части сложного предложения."Ну" здесь заменяет вводное слово "в общем".

***Это я на геометрии, физике, химии, биологии - ну, вы поняли.***